# list of objects to Collections.map

Tags: f#

Given a list kinda like (simplified):

```
type foo(n:string,m:string,l:string) = 
    member f.name=n
    member f.val1=m
    member f.val2=l
let dates = [
    foo("a","aa","aaa")
    foo("b","bb","bbb")
]
```

How can a a immutable dictionary-type structure (eg, Map, IDictionary...any others?) of the form `key:foo.name,value:foo` be made?

My best guess was

```
let fooDict = for f in foo do yield f.name,f
```

But that for-comprehension syntax can only be used to make a list, array, or seq?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To create an immutable dictionary (the interface is mutable, but will throw an exception if you try to modify it)

```
[ for f in dates -> f.name,f ] |> dict
```

or

```
dates |> Seq.map (fun f -> f.name, f) |> dict
```

To create an immutable Map:

```
[ for f in dates -> f.name,f ] |> Map.ofSeq
```

or

```
dates |> Seq.map (fun f -> f.name, f) |> Map.ofSeq
```

Comment: Nice. I didn't understand that I could pipe the yield tuple into a Map.ofSeq. Very helpful to see the syntactical options.

Comment: @Gustavo : Didn't know about dict, nice shorthand, but it creates an immutable dictionary, not mutable. It seems to use an object expression, so the type is not immediately obvious: `d.GetType().FullName`-> Microsoft.FSharp.Core.ExtraTopLevelOperators+CreateDictionary@52 .. type params. But you can't assign to the resulting IDictionary.

Comment: Humm, when you try to add items it throws a NotSupportedException, didn't know about that, I assumed it returned a normal dictionary. I've updated the answer

Comment: Without looking at source, I'm guessing F# Map buried in an object expression. :)

Answer (score 4):

I ended up with the more verbose (and ignorant of pipes):

```
Map.ofList([for f in foo do yield (f.name,f)])
```

Comment: Note that the parentheses around the list are not required - that actually makes this notation quite nice (I think).

Comment: And if you use -> instead of do yield it gets even nicer: `Map.ofList [for f in foo -> f.name,f]`

Answer (score 3):

Check out the [`dict`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353774.aspx) function -- it takes a sequence of key-value tuples and creates an immutable dictionary from them.

With a list like the one you provided, you could use `Seq.map` to create the sequence, then pipe it into `dict`.

Comment: Concretely, `dates |> Seq.map (fun f -> f.name, f) |> dict` or `dates |> Seq.map (fun f -> f.name, f) |> Map.ofSeq`.